# Trouble getting cognito JWT token back when using Google sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Having trouble getting API Gateway JWT Token using Google Sign In.

Use Case:
We have a cognito user pool set up to use Google as an Identity provider. We also have a set of API endpoints in API Gateway, some of which require an **Authorization** header to access the endpoint. We have a **cognito_user_pool** authorizer attached to some of the routes. When loging in with a *cognito user* (user signed up to the pool directly and went through account/email verification) I get a JWT token back. I am then able to make API Gateway requests and all is right with the world.

It was my understanding (based on assumption of course...) that when using a 3rd party provider, I would login into the provider (google) get a token back that I would then exchange for a **cognito JWT token** I could then make API requests with. After much digging, it turns out that behavior is **NOT** supported. From what I can tell from a myriad of blog posts and stack overflow, is that you *can* get credentials to then use other AWS resources but only through the AWS-SDK or a generated API Gateway SDK, which makes no sense in the context of an API...

I am wondering if anyone else has this use case, and how they worked around it while continuing to use cognito as the user management sysytem, or if there are any plans on the part of AWS to enable some form of this behavior? Somewhat related t: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231850

Comment: I was running a semi-automated functional test suite using cypress and tried to do this. The answer below was helpful but in the end I still could not get my session established so ended up just writing browser click actions to complete a signup using the Cognito UI my answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435696/2827300)

Answer (score 3):

So, as far as I understand, you want to authenticate your API with Google SignIn but it currently works only if you use the Cognito token i.e sign-in using Userpool username + password. If so, then I faced the same issue a while back. It is possible to use Google with Cognito Userpool Authorizer and I was able to do the same.

- It takes only ID tokens
- It recognizes only Cognito tokens i.e. **iss** claim should be cognito idp & not Google, Facebook etc.
- You need to sign-in using either the Cognito Userpool's built-in UI (the easiest way or you can use the /authorize endpoint to skip the UI). Of course, you should have Google enabled as an IdP for an App Client. On the Cognito page select Google & sign-in. You will get a pair of id & access tokens. Use the ID token in API Gateway. The URL of the built-in UI would be :

  https://your_domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?redirect_uri=https://www.yourpage.com&response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- The app client with this client id should have Google enabled as an IdP in **App Client Settings** in the Userpool console.
- The reason why this works is that Google sends the Auth response back to your Cognito userpool domain's  https://your-user-pool-domain/oauth2/idpresponse . After this Cognito uses this info to vend COgnito id & access tokens with Google claims in the Identity section. Now, as the issuer is Cognito, these tokens can be used in te API Gateway's Cognito userpool Authorizer
- Cognito does not support exchanging third-party tokens for Cognito tokens directly (as of now). You can use third-party tokens to get temporary AWS credentials using Cognito Identity Pool or you can use Cognito' domain i.e the builtin-UI (/login endpoint) or the /authorize endpoint to directly get token's using third-party signin. But, as of now, you can not explicitly exchange one token for another.

Comment: Thanks!! Interesting, I will give this a shot today! My only concern is the redirect_uri parameter, as this is a native mobile app

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this in 2022?

Comment: I found this link which seems to walk through how to do the above: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/11/02/bypass-cognito-hosted-ui/